# How to increase table width

Tags: css, vue.js, datatable, width

[image]I am trying to increase table width and fill extra spaces but columns are not changing with respect to width I am giving width to my  like below:

```
            <tr v-for="user in paginatedUsers" :key="user.id">
                <td style="width: 10%">{{user.id}}</td>
                <td style="width: 30%">{{user.case_id}}</td>
                <td style="width: 40%">{{user.user_id}}</td>
                <td style="width: 50%">{{user.message_title}}</td>
                <td style="width: 60%">{{user.process_type}}</td>
                <td style="width: 70%">{{user.msg_code}}</td>
                <td style="width: 80%">{{user.log_type}}</td>
                <td style="width: 90%">{{user.created_at}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

I have also attach my screen shot of my datatable:

[image]

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Add inline style to table  style="width:100%"  remove td columns width inline style  check example  Flexible table width https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html

Answer (score 0):

Total width of the columns should be 100%. Please try this one.

```
<tr v-for="user in paginatedUsers" :key="user.id">
    <td style="width: 5%">{{user.id}}</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">{{user.case_id}}</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">{{user.user_id}}</td>
    <td style="width: 20%">{{user.message_title}}</td>
    <td style="width: 20%">{{user.process_type}}</td>
    <td style="width: 5%">{{user.msg_code}}</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">{{user.log_type}}</td>
    <td style="width: 20%">{{user.created_at}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I see that your title is longer as well. That can also influence the size. You can tweak a bit on that as well.

Comment: I have attached the screen shot

Comment: Try to make it shorter. Like "Message Code" to "Code".

Comment: I have tried and short my titles and output is attached